# url rewrite for internationalization

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm implementation internationalization in my site and i would like users to be able to enter urls such as :

```
http://www.mysite.com/en/showprofile.php?id=1000
http://www.mysite.com/de/showprofile.php?id=1000
```

and have this rewritten to

```
http://www.mysite.com/showprofile.php?id=1000&lang=en
http://www.mysite.com/showprofile.php?id=1000&lang=de
```

From what i understand this can be done with url rewriting in my .htaccess file am not too sure about the exact syntax. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (..)/(.*)$ $2&lang=$1
```

The rationale is: Take the language code (the two first characters) as a first regex result, then the rest of the URL (till the `$`) as the second regex result. Finally, use the rest of the URL, and append the `&lang=$1` part (`$1` and `$2` denote the first and second matches of parts within parentheses).